# How do i display api responses in text widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following image, I am using the post method to send the data, which is successfully done and when the server returns the response which is can be seen in the user's console, now how do I display those responses in text widgets in another class?

**This is my Api class where I use post method.**

```
class APIService {
  Future<DoctorResponseLoginModels> register(
      DoctorRequestLoginModels doctorLoginRequestModels) async {


    String url = "http://202.51.75.142:9028/api/PatientMaster/PostPatientLogin";

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var globalToken = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
    print("$globalToken");

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $globalToken',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(doctorLoginRequestModels));

    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    DoctorResponseLoginModels responseModel =
        DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(responseJson);

    print("This is ${response.body}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      sharedPreferences.setInt('code', response.statusCode);
      var StatusCode = sharedPreferences.getInt('code');
      print("This contains : $StatusCode");
      print(response.statusCode);


      return DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }
}
```

**This is my Request Class model which I sent to server**

```
DoctorRequestLoginModels doctorRequestLoginModelsFromJson(String str) =>
    DoctorRequestLoginModels.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String doctorRequestLoginModelsToJson(DoctorRequestLoginModels data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class DoctorRequestLoginModels {
  DoctorRequestLoginModels({
    required this.code,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  String code;
  String username;
  String password;

  factory DoctorRequestLoginModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      DoctorRequestLoginModels(
        code: json["code"],
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      };
}
```

**This is my Response Models class which I need to display in text**

```
DoctorResponseLoginModels doctorResponseLoginModelsFromJson(String str) =>
    DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String doctorResponseLoginModelsToJson(DoctorResponseLoginModels data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class DoctorResponseLoginModels {
  DoctorResponseLoginModels({
    this.doctorId,
    this.nmCno,
    this.doctorName,
    this.contactNo,
    this.username,
    this.emailId,
    this.strEmail,
    this.id,
    this.intMobile,
    this.gender,
    this.currentAddress,
    this.depId,
    this.entryDate,
    this.password,
    this.code,
    this.isActive,
    this.hospitalName,
    this.department,
    this.deviceId,
    this.profile,
    this.token,
    this.role,
  });

  int? doctorId;
  String? nmCno;
  String? doctorName;
  String? contactNo;
  dynamic? username;
  String? emailId;
  String? strEmail;
  int? id;
  String? intMobile;
  dynamic? gender;
  String? currentAddress;
  int? depId;
  String? entryDate;
  dynamic? password;
  dynamic? code;
  bool? isActive;
  dynamic? hospitalName;
  dynamic? department;
  dynamic? deviceId;
  String? profile;
  String? token;
  String? role;

  factory DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      DoctorResponseLoginModels(
        doctorId: json["doctorID"],
        nmCno: json["nmCno"],
        doctorName: json["doctorName"],
        contactNo: json["contactNo"],
        username: json["username"],
        emailId: json["emailID"],
        strEmail: json["strEmail"],
        id: json["id"],
        intMobile: json["intMobile"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        currentAddress: json["currentAddress"],
        depId: json["depId"],
        entryDate: json["entryDate"],
        password: json["password"],
        code: json["code"],
        isActive: json["isActive"],
        hospitalName: json["hospitalName"],
        department: json["department"],
        deviceId: json["deviceId"],
        profile: json["profile"],
        token: json["token"],
        role: json["role"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "doctorID": doctorId,
        "nmCno": nmCno,
        "doctorName": doctorName,
        "contactNo": contactNo,
        "username": username,
        "emailID": emailId,
        "strEmail": strEmail,
        "id": id,
        "intMobile": intMobile,
        "gender": gender,
        "currentAddress": currentAddress,
        "depId": depId,
        "entryDate": entryDate,
        "password": password,
        "code": code,
        "isActive": isActive,
        "hospitalName": hospitalName,
        "department": department,
        "deviceId": deviceId,
        "profile": profile,
        "token": token,
        "role": role,
      };
}
```

**This is where I am using Future Builder to display in Text**

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 10),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              height: 150.0,
              width: 150.0,
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              child: FutureBuilder<DoctorResponseLoginModels>(
                future: APIService().register(DoctorRequestLoginModels(
                    code: "code", username: "username", password: "password")),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Text('Loading....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        DoctorResponseLoginModels data = snapshot.data!;

                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(data.doctorName!),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                  }
                },
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ));
```

**And this is the image of response I get in my console after I use post method and this is the response which I need to display in my text widgets**

[image: And this is the image of response I get in my console after I use post method and this is the response which I need to display in my text widgets]

Comment: I think it could be done like that Text(listData[which one you want to call][doctorID].toString) and this will retrieve the data into text widget

Comment: could you add your ui code too and the way you are calling register?

Comment: in your UI you can access the values/properties like this: ``data.doctorID``, ``data.nmCno`` and so on, where ``data`` is the variable name in whihc you;'re receiving the response in your UI part.

Comment: @MousaAlribi no it doesn't work, anything else??

Comment: @eamirho3ein I haven't called it yet, rather I don't know how, if u do tell.

Comment: @OMiShah, nope it won't work

Comment: @Mr.Robot could you add your DoctorResponseLoginModels class?

Comment: @eamirho3ein, in the below given code, in "future: APIService().register(...)" , what parameters do i put in register cause I tried adding DoctorResponseLoginModels but it showed error

Comment: @eamirho3ein I did but it throws error saying "Error:type'Null' is not a subtype of int "and it shows error in my emulator not in console.

Comment: @eamirho3ein yah sure, I edited my post and added everything I have done till now, hope you'll see it, and thanks for ur time till now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be to put the API-Class to a Provider.

Access the Instance whenever you need.

Comment: how do i do that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
FutureBuilder<DoctorResponseLoginModels>(
    future: APIService().register(...),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Loading....');
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            DoctorResponseLoginModels data = snapshot.data!;

            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(data.doctorName ?? ''),
                Text(data.username?? ''),
              ],
            );
          }
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: in the below given code, in "future: APIService().register(...)" , what parameters do i put in register cause I tried adding DoctorResponseLoginModels but it showed error

Comment: this is the part you should tell me. from you code i assume it is something that you want to send to api.

Comment: I did but it throws error saying "Error:type'Null' is not a subtype of int "and it shows error in my emulator not in console.

Comment: can you tell me how did you call your api?

Comment: yah sure, I edited my post and added everything I have done till now, hope you'll see it.